# Queue<T> under concurrency giving different results for different types

Tags: c#, .net, collections, concurrency

I'm just getting to know some of the new .NET concurrent collections like ConcurrentDictionary and ConcurrentQueue and I was running some tests to see what happens when I write parallel to the Queue.

So I ran this:

```
    private static void ParallelWriteToQueue(Queue<int> queue)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.For(1,1000001,(i) => queue.Enqueue(i));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Regular int Queue - " + queue.Count + " time" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

And as I thought I got the next exception:

```
Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
```

So this Queue can't handle concurrent en-queues as predicted.

**But**, When I changed the type of the queue to string, there was no exception, and the result writes something like

```
Regular string Queue - 663209 time117
```

Which means that only about 663k were en-queued.

Why was there no exception?

What happened to all of the not en-queued items?

this is the same function with Queue

```
    private static void ParallelWriteToQueue(Queue<string> queue)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.For(1, 100001, (i) => queue.Enqueue(i.ToString()));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Regular string Queue - " + queue.Count + " time" + +sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: You only run the second parallel for loop to 100001 instead of 1000001.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth sorry I changed it right before copying... it ran the same number of iterations

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Sometimes you hit an error, and sometimes you don't.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's the best and simplest answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not you get an exception has nothing to do with the type you put in the queue. It is non-deterministic, I can reproduce the exception for both types and I can reproduce the case without exception also for both types - without changes to the code.

Running the following snippet shows this:

```
int exceptions = 0;
int noExceptions = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x)
{
    Queue<int> q = new Queue<int>();
    try
    {
        Parallel.For(1,1000001,(i) => q.Enqueue(i)); 
        ++noExceptions;
    }
    catch
    {
        ++exceptions;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Runs with exception: {0}. Runs without: {1}", exceptions, noExceptions);
```

The output is something like `Runs with exception: 96. Runs without: 4`

The reason is - as others already mentioned - that `Queue` is not thread safe. What happens here is called ["Race condition"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_Condition).

Comment: I tried this function myself but exceptions weren't caught, why is that?

Comment: Try increasing the count from 100 to 1000 of the outer for loop. As this is undefined behavior and therefore non-deterministic it can be any number of reasons. Maybe your computer is too fast, too slow, has too much memory or too little. There is really no telling...

Comment: Sorry, I'll rephrase... Exceptions were thrown, but not caught... ie, execution was halted and I got the little window with Exception was unhandled by user code...

Comment: Run it without debugger attached... (Ctrl + F5 instead of F5 on my machine)

Comment: Ok thanks, I ran it too and of course you were right I get exceptions with strings and ints, but after running it I noticed that an int queue "usually" failes 95% of the time, and a string queue "usually" fails around 60% of the time (check it yourself, I ran it many times and the results were pretty consistent), so is there any reason this should be? I'm just curious that's all :)

Comment: @Mithir: Yes, I observed the same results.The reason is the following: In the string case, each item you put in the queue takes a bit longer as in the int case, because we first have to create that string. This results in a lower probability of two threads accessing the queue at the same time. You can simulate this with the int variant when you put a `Thread.Sleep(0)` after the `Enqueue`: `Parallel.For(1,1000001,(i) => {q.Enqueue(i); Thread.Sleep(0);});`. Now it will fail only about 60% of the time. A classical race condition: it is heavily dependent on timing.

Answer (score 4):

[`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) as opposed to [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) is not thread safe, as per MSDN. The rest of the behavior you describe happens by chance from collisions arising from concurrent (multi-threaded) write access, purely based on the fact `Queue<T>` isn't thread safe.

Answer (score 2):

The standard collection implementations are not thread-safe, a your test shows. The fact that an exception is thrown with ints, but not strings is likely just chance, and you may get different results if you try the test again.

As far as the "lost" items, it's not possible to determine - the queue's internal state is likely corrupt as a result of the multithreaded access, so the count could itself be wrong, or the items may simply not have been enqueued.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Parallel.For()`, the collection must be **thread-safe** to provide normal work.

So, consider using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` class.

Comment: my question wasn't about that, it was about why it gave different results for different types

Comment: @Mithir, because the implementation is not thread-safe. It guarantees nothing!