# Is Queue<T>.Enqueue(T) method thread-safe when it is used alone?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, queue

Would it be thread-safe if I solely call `Enqueue(T)` from multiple threads simultaneously and wait for those threads to complete before calling `Dequeue()` or enumerating the queue?

```
var queue = new Queue<int>();
Action enqueue = () =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        queue.Enqueue(i);
};

var tasks = new[]
{
    new Task(enqueue),
    new Task(enqueue),
    new Task(enqueue)
};
foreach (var task in tasks)
    task.Start();

Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, t =>
{
    while (queue.Count > 0)
        Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) if you want a thread safe queue?

Comment: @nemesv: I only need to call Enqueue method from multiple threads, if the sample in my question is thread-safe, I don't need to use ConcurrentQueue.

Comment: @Daniel: Can you post a "You get this exception if you try to do that" kind of answer so I can accept?

Comment: @ŞafakGür: Adam already posted an answer that tells you it is not thread safe. You could accept this.

Comment: @Daniel: Just saw it, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) also states that instance members of this type are **not** thread safe (scroll down to the Thread Safety section).

The documentation also states:

> A Queue can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified.

However, this is just a by-product of the fact that concurrent reading does not mutate the list. It does **not** make the type "thread-safe". Thread-safety is best thought of as offering *true* support across all actions that define the *public contract* of the type (in this case, thread-safety in mutating the list also).

More tongue-in-cheek: the implementation of Enqueue doesn't include any thread synchronisation or locking primitives:

```
public void Enqueue(T item)
{
    if (this._size == this._array.Length)
    {
        int num = (int)((long)this._array.Length * 200L / 100L);
        if (num < this._array.Length + 4)
        {
            num = this._array.Length + 4;
        }
        this.SetCapacity(num);
    }
    this._array[this._tail] = item;
    this._tail = (this._tail + 1) % this._array.Length;
    this._size++;
    this._version++;
}
```

So I'm going with "no". There is [`ConcurrentQueue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) for multi-threaded support.

Comment: +1: A practical example of what happens when multiple threads enqueue can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981777/572644). Note the non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: The most important factor is what the docs say, not what the *current* implementation does. The impl can change anytime, including between patch levels.

Comment: @usr I actually updated my answer to point at the documentation before you commented.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, did not see that edit. Still, this answer suggests (probably unintentionally) that looking at the implementation proves something. It doesn't.

Comment: @usr No the answer is meant to be tongue-in-cheek at it not being thread-safe. The documentation is normally stop number one. I disagree that it doesn't prove anything. The code proves everything. The point I believe you are making is that it only proves it for a particular version of the code, and is not exactly a strong contract to program against. Unfortunately, neither is the documentation is some cases. The simple fact is that there is no compiler supported contract that enforces usage of thread-safe types in multi-threaded scenarios.

Comment: @usr But either way, I'll update my answer for more clarity as I *do* agree with you that the documentation is usually the best source of information on a type's public contract.

Comment: I actually read the documentation before asking this. It just wasn't clear enough (for me). It gave me the idea that the Queue<T> can be thread safe if the only operation I do is "adding" but the implementation you posted shows that I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @ŞafakGür I read the documentation (for 4.5) and it states that it is thread-safe for read actions, but not mutating actions (i.e. adding / removing / updating). Either way, glad it's all clear.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth arg! look at what Safak just said. It might be that he thinks the implementation could have proved thread-safety (it can only prove non-safety of course). Maybe I'm crazy but I think people are so easily mislead by this. Anyway, your answer clarifies this as much as possible.

Comment: @ŞafakGür Yeah I see where the confusion can creep in. SO is for clearing up these programming problems :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is important: If the docs don't say the queue is thread-safe, it isn't. (And for Queue, they say it is not thread-safe).

Looking at the internals is a weak test: The internals might change any time to a non-thread-safe version.

Don't rely on undocumented properties except under unusual circumstances.

Comment: And only rely on documentation from a body as large as Microsoft. In my experience, documentation (though largely not from Microsoft) is also a weak test.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this will be threadsafe since Queue is not thread safe. You are sharing same instance to different threads.

> A Queue can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx

You need to implement your own synchronization (i.e., use lock()), or use ConcurrentQueue (System.Collections.Concurrent).

Comment: There is no `queue.IsSynchronized` property.

Comment: And if there would be one, it would be false always.

Comment: Apologies; that's a private property. Fixed.